# DOTNET core The call is ambiguous between methods Configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Getting Error

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions.UseConfiguration(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsWebHostBuilderExtensions.UseConfiguration

in line `.UseConfiguration(ConfigurationRoot)`

#### My Method

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings-{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("azure")}.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args);

ConfigurationRoot = builder.Build();

var application = new WebHostBuilder()
  .UseConfiguration(ConfigurationRoot)
  .UseIISIntegration()
  .UseServer("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel")
  .UseStartup<Startup>()
  .Build();
application.Run();
```

#### Project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Aps.ManageIT.WebAPI",
  "authors": [ "IPPCS" ],
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "copyToOutput": {
      "include": [ "wwwroot" ],
      "includeFiles": [
        "appsettings.json",
        "appsettings-dev.json",
        "web.config",
        "appsettings-aps.json",
        "appsettings-adidasdev.json",
        "appsettings-prod.json"
      ]
    },
    "compile": [
      "wwwroot"
    ]
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [ "wwwroot" ],
    "includeFiles": [
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings-dev.json",
      "web.config",
      "appsettings-aps.json",
      "appsettings-adidasdev.json",
      "appsettings-prod.json"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Aps.ManageIT.Repository.MongoDB": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "OpenIddict": "1.0.0-alpha2-0288",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "mongocsharpdriver": "2.2.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "HtmlAgilityPack": "1.4.9.4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Aps.JobIT.Log.Repository.MongoDB": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "8.0.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {}
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the packages you are referencing are old pre-release packages. Update your packages to stable versions.

Before the 1.0.0 release, a change has been made moving this extension method from `WebHostBuilderExtensions` to `.Abstractions`. The pre-release packages you are using define this extension at both places, which is why you are seeing this error. This should be resolved when updating to the released (1.0.0+) packages.

Alternatively, use the full `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsWebHostBuilderExtensions.UseConfiguration(webHostBuilder, configuration)` method instead of chaining configuration method calls through extension methods:

```
var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder();
var application = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsWebHostBuilderExtensions.UseConfiguration(webHostBuilder, ConfigurationRoot)
  .UseIISIntegration()
  .UseServer("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel")
  .UseStartup<Startup>()
  .Build();
application.Run();
```

Comment: edited answer to show this option. (but please don't use it in production - there are several security vulnerabilities in the pre-release packages)

Comment: After applying your changes Exception Throws in same line === Field not found: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostDefaults.ServerKey'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions.UseServer(IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder, String assemblyName)
   at Aps.JobIT.WebAPI.Startup.Main(String[] args) in C:\TFS\SbmAps\Aps\src\Aps.JobIT.WebAPI\Startup.cs:line 196